# Auto Change Status of Order in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to auto Change Status of Order from Shipped (custom status i am using) to Completed but after 10 days. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to:

1. Get all orders that have the status 'shipped' and were created before the last 10 days.
   You can use the wc_get_orders function (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) to query orders.

   ```
   $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
           'status' => 'shipped',
           'date_created' => '<' . ( time() - 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ),
   ```

   ) );
   You can use date_paid instead of date_created -- depends on your needs.
2. Loop through the results of the query and set them all to 'completed'.

   ```
   foreach ($orders as $order){
       $order->update_status( 'completed' );
   }
   ```
3. Schedule the running of this function daily using the wp_schedule_event function
   wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'function_name' );

Put together, you should have this:

```
function setCompletedAfter10Days(){
        $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
                'status' => 'shipped',
                'date_created' => '<' . ( time() - 10 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ),

        ) );

        foreach ($orders as $order){
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
}

wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'setCompletedAfter10Days' );
```

Comment: Thank You for taking time out to write this code for me. I really appreciate it. I put this code in functions.php but nothing has happened even after 24 hours. Did i miss something?

Comment: Can you try putting the schedule event inside a function and then hooking that to the 'wp' action?


// Schedule Cron Job Event
function completeCronJob() {
 if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'setCompletedAfter10Days' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'setCompletedAfter10Days' );
 }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'completeCronJob' );

I'll test it later if I have some spare time today.